# Can you. run "aws ecr get-login-password" when using an assumed role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

Currently I want to interact with an ECR repository that I have access to via an assumed role.

How do I run:

`aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin accountId.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

`docker pull respositylocation:tag`

So that I am able to assume the role, and pull the docker image.

I am able to run other commands within AWS and successfully assume a role to execute the command. It is specifically the aws ecr get-login-password that I am unable to run successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course you can. That's how, for example, CodeBuild logins to the ECR - by using its role.

For this, your role would need to have needed permissions to use ECR. By the [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/setting-up.html#setting-up-service-role) of CodeBuild, your role could have the following policy attached:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ECRPullPolicy",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "ECRAuthPolicy",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

There could be other permissions needed for the role, such as for S3. But the ECR access should be sufficiently handled by the above.